# Resolve returns False on two contradicting statements

Tags: bugs, symbolic, resolve

I'm trying to prove an inequality using Mathematica. This is the code leading to the inequality:

```
T = {{0, pbl*pcharge, 0}, {1, 1 - pbl, psh}, {0, pbl*(1 - pcharge), 
    1 - psh}};
vecs = Eigenvectors[T];
val = Eigenvalues[T];
pfull = Simplify[(1/(1 + vecs[[1]][[1]] + vecs[[1]][[2]]))];
pdead = Simplify[vecs[[1]][[1]]*pfull];
pbl1 = (1 - phigh)*beta/(lowcons + (1 - pfull - pdead)*M);
psh1 = phigh*(highcons - beta)/(pfull*M);
sols = Simplify[Solve[pbl1 == pbl && psh1 == psh, {pbl, psh}]];
pshex2[highcons_, lowcons_, beta_, phigh_, pcharge_, M_] = 
  Simplify[sols[[All, 2, 2]]];
```

However, when I try to use `Resolve[]` to see if the inequality is true, both the inequality and its negation are resolved as false:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{highcons, lowcons, beta, phigh, pcharge, M}, 
  highcons > beta > lowcons > 0 && 0 < phigh < 1 && 0 < pcharge < 1 &&
    M > 0, D[pshex2[highcons, lowcons, beta, phigh, pcharge, M], M] <= 
   0], Reals]
Out[1714]= False

Resolve[Exists[{highcons, lowcons, beta, phigh, pcharge, M}, 
  highcons > beta > lowcons > 0 && 0 < phigh < 1 && 0 < pcharge < 1 &&
    M > 0, D[pshex2[highcons, lowcons, beta, phigh, pcharge, M], M] > 
   0], Reals]
Out[1715]= False
```

Also, `FindInstance[]` is not able to find an example for the second statement. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I'm very new to Mathematica.

Comment: `bugs` is a special tag that is supposed to be added only by someone else than the original poster, after verifying the issue.  Please do not add this tag to *your own* posts.

Comment: It does look like a bug to me, please report this to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know that. Sent the issue to Wolfram Tech Support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found your example a bit hard to follow, so let's write in a form which is more explicit:

```
expr = First@D[pshex2[highcons, lowcons, beta, phigh, pcharge, M], M];

cond = highcons > beta > lowcons > 0 && 0 < phigh < 1 && 0 < pcharge < 1 && M > 0;
```

In version 10.0.2 or later (up to 11.0.1):

```
Resolve[ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* False *)

Resolve[Not@ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* False *)

Resolve[Exists[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr > 0], Reals]
(* False *)
```

`ForAll` is (surprisingly!) `HoldAll` so `Evaluate` was necessary int he first argument.

The second input above is literally the same as the first one except for wrapping the `ForAll` in `Not`.

The conditions are clearly fine and there are many combinations of values that satisfy them (`FindInstance[cond, Variables[expr]]`).

In version 9.0.1:

```
Resolve[ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* True *)

Resolve[Not@ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* False *)

Resolve[Exists[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond, expr > 0], Reals]
(* False *)
```

It seems clear that there's a bug in v10.0.2 – 11.0.1.  Is the result by v9.0.1 correct? That I do not know.

Comment: Thank you for checking this out! Can you please explain why Variables is needed to be used inside Evaluate?

Comment: @Venomouse Because `ForAll` has the `HoldAll` attribute, which I find quite weird for a symbolic processing function ... I asked about this here, and included examples that show what would happen without `Evaluate`: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/937146

Answer (score 4):

Note that expr is a rational function. If the denominator of expr is zero, then the inequality `expr<=0` is neither true nor false -- it is undefined. Hence it is not true that for all values of variables that satisfy cond the inequality `expr<=0` is true. If we add the condition `Denominator[expr]!=0` then we get the expected result.

```
Resolve[ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond && Denominator[expr]!=0, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* True *)

Resolve[Not@ForAll[Evaluate@Variables[expr], cond && Denominator[expr]!=0, expr <= 0], Reals]
(* False *)
```